# Carrierwave changing filename path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have an issue with how CarrierWave is saving my images. It is changing the file name to something else. 
For example, if I upload an image with the file name say 1058587592.jpg. 
The path that I get ends up being something like this [image: %5bnil%2c%20%221058587592].
What is happening

Comment: faced same issue before , on changing version of `gem ' carrierwave'` issue resolved. you can try stable version of gem.

Comment: Did you change yours to a specific version? As i have tried installing both the edge version

        gem "carrierwave", :github => "carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave"
and just a plain version
        gem "carrierwave" even
        gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
and nothing seems to work